# VSCode нужно настроить

Tags: javascript, html, visual-studio-code

всем привет! не могу понять как решить эту проблему если есть решения, не работает подсказки и автозаполнения в обратных кавычках в JS файле. можно сделать так чтоб и в js файле можно было в обратных кавычках писать с автозаполнением ?
[image: Это проблема]

[image: как тут должно всплывать подсказки]

Comment: Чтобы не получать минусы на каждый подобный вопрос, вот чатик по IDE и простым редакторам в телеге https://t.me/ide_ru

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Подобный вопрос уже был в англоязычной версии: [JSX or HTML autocompletion in Visual Studio Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39320393/jsx-or-html-autocompletion-in-visual-studio-code).

Так же есть более свежий материал на эту тему: [Enable Emmet support for JSX in Visual Studio Code | React](https://medium.com/@eshwaren/enable-emmet-support-for-jsx-in-visual-studio-code-react-f1f5dfe8809c).

В общем случае всё сводится к добавлению данного конфига в настройки VSCode:

```json
{
   "emmet.includeLanguages": {
      "javascript": "javascriptreact"
   }
}
```